# Delete data using php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

It's possible create code can delete data in table after specific time given from user using php and pdo or something similar and how i do it?

```
public function delete_time($thedata,$time){


}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to execute a `DELETE` statement on a database from PHP.

Comment: Much too broad. You're just asking how to execute a `delete`. Also note that using `PDO` won't secure you from SQL injections, you'll need to use parameterized queries. Here's what Google would have given you; http://webdevelopingcat.com/deleting-rows-in-a-mysql-database-using-php-pdo-extension/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague and so my answer must be vague as well, but I believe you can do what you want using the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html). You can create a SQL statement to schedule a query (such as a `DELETE`) to run once or repeatedly at a future time:

```
CREATE EVENT future_delete
  ON SCHEDULE AT <timestamp>
  DO CALL my_delete_procedure(<param1>, <param2>);
```

I should imagine you could wrap this in a stored procedure that you could then invoke from php, passing bound values for `<timestamp>`, `<param1>`, `<param2>` &c.

Hope that's of some use to you.